# How do I change service requires to mock requires when running unit tests in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

Consider I have the following code in my server file:

```
// Internal modules
const authenticationService = require('../services/authenticationService');
// Setup
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Init routing
require('./controllers/authenticationController')(app, authenticationService);

app.listen(8081, (err) => {
    if (err) throw new Error('Could not start the server');
});
```

Now this is fine and will work. But what if I run unit tests and want to replace authenticationService with a mocked version? I don't want to hit my real database when executing tests against my API. Am I structuring this wrong or how should I approach this? I know I can use different mocking modules to fake the authenticationService away but honestly I don't enjoy using sinon etc too much. I'd rather write my own mock services this time. Any ideas / help?

Comment: First thing should be to export the app variable so it can be tested. Instead of sinon, in this scenario, I think [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) could help you. You can find the docs in the link. Basically it allow you to require app from your tests and pass mock variables for your dependencies

Comment: Proxyquire seems like it could do the job. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Sinon is a good way to build an mock/stub Object.

But it need you to inject the mock/stub object into your servrice code and the premise is that the code is consistent with the dependency inversion principle

So I think the [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) module could help you. By using rewire you can make overriding dependencies easy without modifying existing code.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Instead of directly doing

```
require('../services/authenticationService');
```

in your module, your module should accept authenticationService as a dependency. So if you encapsulate your code into a module, say SomeModule.js:

```
module.exports = function SomeModule(authenticationService, app, otherDependencies /* such as bodyParser etc. as needed. */) {
  this.start = function(port) {
    // your code goes here
    // more code
    app.listen(8081, (err) => {
       if (err) throw new Error('Could not start the server');
    });
  }
}
```

then in your production code you can call it like this:

```
var myModule = new SomeModule(require('../services/authenticationService'), app /* and all other dependencies required by SomeModule.*/);
module.start(8081);
```

and in your test code you can call it like this:

```
 var myModule = new SomeModule(require('../mocks/mockAuthenticationService'), app /* and all other dependencies required by SomeModule.*/);
 module.start(8081);
```